# Prefix tree vs TreeSet

Tags: java, data-structures

I have implemented a contacts search application using a prefix tree in java. and came across a solution for the same problem using a TreeSet.
In which cases should I use prefix tree and in which cases should I use TreeSet ?

Comment: Please add the research you have done about the two options, and why this research does not answer your question.

Comment: when searching for contacts it should autocomplete. for example typed Dan, it should return Dan and Danny and all other matches.
i was hoping for a rule of thumb when to use which data structure. 
lets say I have a thousand contacts log(n) in TreeSet is just 10. not too bad i think. and shorter than most contacts names first + surename O(m) in prefix tree . memory allocation prefix tree node in some implementations holds an array in the size of the entire abc. but when looking up in google / stack overflow everyone is talking about prefix tree so i guess im missing something.

Comment: Please add it to the *question*, in a properly formatted and readable way. This information should be in the question, not in the comment. Also include the algorithm that allows you to do the autocompletion using TreeSet.

Answer (score -1):

Trie-Tree is fast solution for searching by prefix in large number or entries. you should use it when user typed prefix of String to search.
it find elements with O(m) where m is length of prefix!
I'm not sure how do you want to implement that with TreeSet, so I don't have any idea to compare them.